# Pagination in post loop. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, pagination, posts

How to make limited to 20 post per site **pagination**
ps. I've make this in content-postarchives.php

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 20 );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
    <h4><a class="text_aktualnosci" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <span class="data_dodania_arch"><?php _e('Data dodania: '); ?><strong><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></strong></span>
    </h4>
    </li>
  <?php endwhile; ?><!-- end of the loop -->
  <!-- put pagination functions here -->
<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Przepraszamy, brak aktualności' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in wp admin:

go to read on setting menu
then change Posts per page.